# Disaggregating data from months to weeks in SAS

Tags: date, sas

I am stuck with a problem where I have two tables, one at the months and one at the weeks. Here's the format of the tables:

```
     Table1

     Customer            Date1          Sales

      1                 Jan2018        1110
      1                 Feb2018        1245
      1                 Mar2018        1320
      1                 Apr2018        1100   
      ...



              Table2

                 Customer              Date2           

                   1                  01Jan2018
                   1                  08Jan2018
                   1                  15Jan2018    
                   1                  22Jan2018
                   1                  29Jan2018
                   1                  05Feb2018
                   1                  12Feb2018       
                   1                  19Feb2018       
                   1                  26Feb2018        
                   1                  05Mar2018
                   ...
```

I want to create a new column for sales in Table2 that will hold the disaggregated values of sales from Table1. I want to divide the sales by the number of days in that month and then assign the values to the weeks accordingly. Thus the sales in week 01Jan2018 is (1110/31)*7. The weeks that are in transition will get values from both the months. For example 29Jan2018 has 3 days in Jan2018 and 4 days in Feb2018. The sales of one day in Jan2018 is 1110/31 and the sales of one day in Feb2018 is 1245/28.

So the sales in week 29Jan2018 will be 3*(1110/31) + 4*(1245/28)

I want to do this for each distinct customer.

The resulting table should be

```
               Result Table

              Customer      Date               Sales           
              1             01Jan2018          250.6      i.e (1110/31)*7
              1             08Jan2018          250.6
              1             15Jan2018          250.6 
              1             22Jan2018          250.6 
              1             29Jan2018          282.27
              1             05Feb2018          311.25 
              1             12Feb2018          311.25    
              1             19Feb2018          311.25
              1             26Feb2018          133.39 + 170.32
```

Thanks!

Comment: How does *29Jan2018 have 3 days in Jan2018 and 4 days in Feb2018*?

Comment: Going by your want, you won't get the exact picture of the sales if you convert month to week. Do you split it in equal proportions, or apply a weight? How do you calculate the weight? There will be an ambiguity in your calculation that way. Meaning it won't show the correct result. _Why don't you aggregate weekly sales to monthly sales and change the calculations?_

Comment: Do you have SAS ETS? I believe both PROC EXPAND and/or TIMESERIES will do this for you if you have that module.

Answer (score 0):

In DATA Step programming you will be needing some 'FORWARD' data instead of some 'LAG' data.  A forward value can be emulated by creating a view to the same data starting one observation forward (obs=2).  After understanding the renaming semantics, it is only a matter of some easy 'bookkeeping'.

```
data customer_months;
attrib Customer length=8 Date1 informat=monyy. format=monyy7.; input 
Customer   Date1  Sales; datalines;
1        Jan2018  1110
1        Feb2018  1245
1        Mar2018  1320
1        Apr2018  1100
run;

* week data, also with computation for month the week is in;
data customer_weeks;
attrib Customer length=8 Date2 informat=date9. format=date9.; input
Customer  Date2;
Date1 = intnx('month', Date2, 0);
datalines;
  1      01Jan2018
  1      08Jan2018
  1      15Jan2018
  1      22Jan2018
  1      29Jan2018
  1      05Feb2018
  1      12Feb2018
  1      19Feb2018
  1      26Feb2018
  1      05Mar2018
run;

* next months sales keyed on prior month value;
data customer_next_months_view / view=customer_next_months_view;
  set customer_months;
  Date1 = intnx('month',Date1,-1);  * the month this record will be a forward for;
  rename Sales=Sales_next_month;
  if _n_ > 1;
run;

* merge original and forward data, rename for making clear the variable roles;
data combined;
  length disag_sales 8;

  merge 
    customer_months  (rename=Sales=Sales_this_month)
    customer_next_months_view
    customer_weeks
  ;
  by Date1;

  days_in_this_month = intck('day',intnx('month',Date1,0),intnx('month',Date1,1));
  days_in_next_month = intck('day',intnx('month',Date1,1),intnx('month',Date1,2));

  day_rate_this_month = Sales_this_month / days_in_this_month;
  day_rate_next_month = Sales_next_month / days_in_next_month;

  if Date2 then 
    if month(Date2) = month(Date2+6) then 
      week_days_this_month = 7;
    else
      week_days_this_month = intck('day', Date2, intnx('month', Date2, 1));

  week_days_next_month = 7 - week_days_this_month;

  dollars_this_week_this_month = week_days_this_month * day_rate_this_month;
  dollars_this_week_next_month = week_days_next_month * day_rate_next_month;

  * desired estimated disaggregated sales;    
  disag_sales = sum (dollars_this_week_this_month,dollars_this_week_next_month);
run;
```